# How to see function of class redis in php

Tags: php, pdo, redis

As the title says,how can i see the function of class `Redis` in the php?How to use it?The same question on the class `Pdo` for me.

Comment: In some kind of manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Redis documentation can be found on there Github repository: https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis

The PDO documentation can be found on php.net:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Thank you,this is all i need.